# Develop and deploy Catalyst app in the same machine

Tags: perl, nginx, catalyst

I have one Catalyst app running fine with Nginx/Fastcgi in one IP of my server (it has another IP with Apache). It uses port:80 and responds perfectly to different domains directed to the same IP.

But when I try to run the Catalyst script/myapp_server.pl -h x.x.x.x to continue with testing, it does not work. If I stop Nginx, It works again. And no luck configuring fastcgi with host:port instead of socket.

The log says that the app is listening in port:3000, but the browser never loads the page.

I need to use the same machine for testing because everything is there (databases, templates, imgs, Javascripts).

What must I configure to run the test server?

Comment: On what port does your fatcgi listen to?

Comment: Nginx listen in :80 and for the fastcgi_pass parameter I tried several: 8080, 9000, 2999, 3001, avoiding the default 3000, just in case. When Fastcgi using socket... I guess it doesn't matter, doesn't it? –

Comment: Fastcgi can listen to a socket OR to a port, you decide: -l /var/run/myapp.socket or -l 127.0.0.1:8000

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your server's firewall allows your ip to receive requests from those ports. Have you taken that into consideration?